# Confused about an intermediate type in Idris

Tags: idris

I'm trying to implement a toy regular type system that ensures a few well formediness side constraints and allows for unfolding mu bindings in it. The data type representing these types contains constructors for fixed point (`Mu`), replacement by the nearest enclosing Mu-bound term (`Var`), and zero and one argument type operators (`Nullary` and `Unary`, respectively).

To ensure some that these types are well-formed they track, as three `Bool` parameters, whether they have a `Mu` as their head constructor, a `Var` as their head constructor, or a `Var` anywhere within them.

```
data A : Bool -- Is Mu headed?
      -> Bool -- Is Var headed?
      -> Bool -- Contains any Var's?
      -> Type where
Mu : A False False _ -> A True False False
Var : A False True True
Nullary : A False False False
Unary : A _ _ m -> A False False m
```

To implement unfolding for Mu-headed types I need to perform substitutions, specifically I need to implement "Mu x. F ====> F[(Mu x. F)/x]".

Other than needing some to generate a proof that the third type parameter works out, the function `subst` seems straightforward:

```
total subst : A m1 v1 c1 -> A m2 v2 c2 -> (c3 ** ((A (m2 || (v2 && m1)) 
                                                     (v2 && v1) 
                                                     c3)
                                             ,(c3 = (c2 && c1))))
subst _ Nullary = (_ ** (Nullary,Refl))
subst w (Unary a) with (subst w a)
  | (c3** (a',aeq)) = (c3 ** (Unary a',aeq))
subst w Var = (_ ** (w,Refl))
subst w (Mu a) = (_ ** (Mu a,Refl))
```

I tried and failed to write a wrapper that cleans up this return type a bit.

```
total subst' : A m1 v1 c1 -> A m2 v2 c2 -> A (m2 || (v2 && m1)) 
                                             (v2 && v1) 
                                             (c2 && c1)
subst' a1 a2 with (subst a2 a2)
  | (_**(a',aeq)) ?=  a'
```

When I try to solve this metavariable, I find that `aeq : x = c2 && Delay c2` not `aeq : x = c2 && Delay c1` as I expected (recall that (`&&`) is lazy in its second argument).

Am I doing something wrong? Is this the expected behaviour? FWIW, I successfully wrote a very similar wrapper for unfold (not shown).

Comment: I have no idea, but it seems a little strange to do so much reasoning with `Bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the problem is the line

```
subst' a1 a2 with (subst a2 a2)
```

Don't you mean to call `subst` on `a1` and `a2`, or the other way around?